# angular row if value change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i have a data = {a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c}

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data" >

   <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div>

</div>
```

and when the value change i would like print

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data" >
 if(value change ) print (<div class="row" >);
   <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div>
 if (value change ) print (</div>);
</div>
```

can you help me please

thanks you

Comment: When does the value change?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: data = {A, A, A, B, b, b, c, c, c} the value change when you have b and when you have c

Comment: Is that data variable even valid javascript? Shouldn't it be [] instead of {}?

Comment: Your question helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have look at [jsfiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/g3t12zmc/)

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data track by $index" >
     <div ng-if="data[$index-1] != data[$index]" class="row" >
       <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div>
     </div>
     <div ng-if="data[$index-1] == data[$index]" class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

You need to track by $index and check whether previous index value is same as current or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated Plunkr](http://jsfiddle.net/nLC3g/640/)

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data track by $index" >
     <div class="row" ng-if="isShowRow($index-1, $index)">
       <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-8" ng-if="!isShowRow($index-1, $index)">{{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

`ng-if` is bound to a scope method here:

```
$scope.isShowRow = function(prevIndex, newIndex) {
  if (prevIndex > -1 && $scope.data[prevIndex]) {
    if ($scope.data[prevIndex] !== $scope.data[newIndex]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Also, I had to add a bit of css to show that `row` element is being added.

Comment: Use `track by $index` if you want to avoid repeat error. Your solution not giving desired output of user. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/nLC3g/635/

Comment: It's not clear that when will the value of `data` array will change, since the watcher will be triggered only then.

Comment: No data is changing means `<div class="row">a a a</div><div class="row">b b b </div>` so on for entire array.

Comment: Ohh.. So it means that when the prevValue != nextValue then ?

Comment: it's possible don't repeat  <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div> because in my program i hava more in  the <div class="row">

Comment: @user3210174 I'll try to make it work without repetition.

Comment: i try this :   $scope.$watch("data", function(newVal, oldVal) {
       console.log(newVal + "; "+oldVal );
       console.log('return ');
    if(newVal == oldVal ) $scope.isShowRow = true;
    else $scope.isShowRow =  false;
    
   });     but i have  always row in the html code

Comment: and the print is :  a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c; a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c
crmInformationController.js:14 return true  he print juste 1 time in the fonction

Comment: @user3210174 The updated solution provides what you asked for: `<div class="row">` when the value changes !

Comment: thanks you it's juste possible don't repeat <div class="col-xs-8">{{value}}</div> juste print or not print the <div class="row'>

Comment: who i do this question is answered